# Turn off the update prompt when republishing a book

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown, rsconnect

When using bookdown::publish_book() to republish a book I get a prompt in the console:

Update application currently deployed at
https://bookdown.org/..../..../? [Y/n]

How can I turn that prompt off?

I need to turn it off since the book should be republished on a regular basis from a script run automatically on an R server. In one of the underlying functions rsconnect::deployApp() I found the option "getOption("rsconnect.force.update.apps", TRUE)" but I can't/don't know how to access that from the publish_book() function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rsconnect::deployApp` function has argument

```
forceUpdate = getOption("rsconnect.force.update.apps", FALSE)
```

If you set that argument to `TRUE`, it should force the update without prompting.  But since you aren't calling `deployApp` directly, you need to set the default value of that argument to be `TRUE`, which you can do by

```
options(rsconnect.force.update.apps = TRUE)
```

You might not want to do this always (sometimes you want the question).  If you want it set only for the duration of your `bookdown::publish_book()` call, do it like this:

```
withr::with_options(c(rsconnect.force.update.apps = TRUE),
                    bookdown::publish_book())
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help!